# Prevent vertical spacing when resizing a Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I have a somewhat simple GUI and I am trying to create buttons and controls for the left side of the window. The right side has a text area which will eventually display content. The left side contains buttons and controls for the user to manipulate. I have used a collection of layout managers (and they seem to be considerably picky) to make what I have now.

I've looked over Oracle's documentation on the BoxLayout which is what the left controls' container is using, and I don't see a way to prevent the buttons from spacing apart when the window is resized. I'd like them to be smashed up at the top and just stay there without spacing out.  BoxLayout's 'glue' feature doesn't really do what you would think it does, it should probably be called a rubber band.

My question is, how do I keep the content on the left from separating wider and wider as the screen gets resized?

My GUI:

```
public class TestCode extends JFrame{

JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea ();
JComboBox <String> typeComboBox;
JTextField searchField;
JTextField fileField;

public TestCode() {
    System.out.println ("In constructor");
    setTitle ("GUI Test");
    setSize (600, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible (true);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton readButton = new JButton("Read File");
    JButton displayButton = new JButton("Display");
    JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");


    searchField = new JTextField(10);
    fileField = new JTextField(15);

    typeComboBox = new JComboBox <String> ();
    typeComboBox.addItem("Index");
    typeComboBox.addItem("Type");
    typeComboBox.addItem("Name");

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JPanel filePanel = new JPanel();
        filePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        filePanel.add(new JLabel("Source file:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        filePanel.add(fileField);
        filePanel.add(readButton);
    JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
        displayPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        displayPanel.add(new JLabel("Display data:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        displayPanel.add(displayButton);
    JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(); 
        searchPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        searchPanel.add(new JLabel ("Search target"));
        searchPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalBox());
        searchPanel.add(searchField);
        searchPanel.add(typeComboBox);
        searchPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalBox());
        searchPanel.add(searchButton);

    container.add(filePanel);
    container.add(displayPanel);
    container.add(searchPanel);
    add(container, BorderLayout.WEST);

    validate();
}
```

Comment: try to use multiple layouts instead of a single layout

Comment: I am, I have box layouts and flow layouts. the box layout is what's allowing the rows to split apart.

Comment: I am not familiar with  BoxLayout, but I would have used AbsoluteLayout for the "left" container in this case. Maybe this is an option.

Comment: Then remove the box layout, put the components in the grid bag layout. BTW what ide are you using?

Comment: @NikolaKolev. Using AbsoluteLayout is a terrible suggestion. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers for too many reasons to be listed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BoxLayout uses the preferredSize as well as the minumimu and maximum sizes to to the layout. In your case the panel will grow from is preferred size to its maximum size as more space is available. To prevent this from happening you can do:

```
filePanel.setMaximumSize( filePanel.getPreferredSize() );
...
displayPanel.setMaximumSize( displayPanel.getPreferredSize() );
...
searchPanel.setMaximumSize( searchPanel.getPreferredSize() );
```

Although a better solution is to  override the `getMaximumSize()` of each panel to return `getPreferredSize()`. You never now when you might use your application in different LAF in which case the preferred size of each panel could change.

Comment: That seems to unexpected and undesired results as well. The filePanel is smashed into a tiny dash no bigger than a '-' and the searchPanel no longer fits on one line, and the button that wraps is hidden below the JPanel height.

Comment: @leigero, The above code works fine. I tested it on your code. You need to set the maximum size AFTER you add all the components to the panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fixed on using Box Layout, then you can use a **Box.Filler** to create an empty area and add it to your left hand side container. Check oracle's documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) under heading **Custom Box.Filler**. In your code, after you add filePanel, displayPanel, searchPanel add a filler with a preferred size that is greater than the resolution that your are supporting. Below is your code with a filler added, so that the content spacing remains intact when resizing.

On the other hand, you can use a Mig Layout and use "wrap" to achieve the same behavior with no special fillers or glues.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCode extends JFrame{

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea ();
    JComboBox typeComboBox;
    JTextField searchField;
    JTextField fileField;

public TestCode() {
    System.out.println ("In constructor");
    setTitle ("GUI Test");
    setSize (600, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible (true);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton readButton = new JButton("Read File");
    JButton displayButton = new JButton("Display");
    JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");


    searchField = new JTextField(10);
    fileField = new JTextField(15);

    typeComboBox = new JComboBox();
    typeComboBox.addItem("Index");
    typeComboBox.addItem("Type");
    typeComboBox.addItem("Name");

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    JPanel filePanel = new JPanel();
        filePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        filePanel.add(new JLabel("Source file:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        filePanel.add(fileField);
        filePanel.add(readButton);
    JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
        displayPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        displayPanel.add(new JLabel("Display data:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        displayPanel.add(displayButton);
    JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(); 
        searchPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        searchPanel.add(new JLabel ("Search target"));
        searchPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalBox());
        searchPanel.add(searchField);
        searchPanel.add(typeComboBox);
        searchPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalBox());
        searchPanel.add(searchButton);

        container.add(filePanel);
        container.add(displayPanel);
        container.add(searchPanel);
        container.add(new Box.Filler(new Dimension(0,100), new Dimension(0,1000), new Dimension(0,1000)));
        add(container, BorderLayout.WEST);

    validate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCode code = new TestCode();
        code.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        code.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Camickrs's solution is the way to go. To make things less spacey, you could enhance it and use a Stream of the panel's/box's components after adding all components to the panel:

```
Stream.of(panel.getComponents()).forEach(component -> component.setMaximumSize(component.getPreferredSize()))
```